# C++: Pointer being freed was not allocated in a class

Tags: c++, class

In the following code I have a int pointer and int variable as data member of a class. I create an instance of the class and print the value the pointer is pointing to.

When the code is executed I get the following output. The error is from when the destructor is invoked:

```
b1.ptr  15    
malloc: *** error for object 0x7ffeefbff49c: pointer being freed was not allocated
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class base{
public:
    int * ptr;
    int val;

    base(int &v1): ptr(&v1){
        val = 20;
    }
    ~base(){
        delete ptr;
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int val = 15;
    base b1 = base(val);
    cout << "b1.ptr  " << *(b1.ptr) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The error message is very clear. You did not allocate the memory pointed to by your pointer with new, so you cannot delete it. The variable you passed, `val`, is allocated on the stack.

Comment: If you are using `delete ptr`, it is your responsibility to avoid undefined behaviour by ensuring that `ptr` is the result of a corresponding `new` expression.   You have not done that.  `&v1` in the constructor, in your example, is the address of a variable in `main()` and that variable was not allocated using ANY variant of operator `new`.

Answer (score 0):

`ptr(&v1)` will initialize `ptr` with the address of `val` (because `v1` is a reference to `val`) which is on the stack.
In `~base()` you're trying to free resources that weren't allocated with `new` therefore you get the error message.

Comment: Thanks you everybody for your respective diagnosis. I modified the code by assigning the **val** variable in main on heap and the code functions fine. But it is the only option I have? 

`int *val = new int(15);`

Comment: You can pass a reference but do `ptr(new int(v1))` so you handle everything here

Answer (score 0):

This is the summary of my understanding of this problem. As soon as pointer variable (ptr) is pointing to a memory location on heap we can delete it. The options which work are:

1. The variable which is passed as a reference to the constructor and subsequently pointed to by the pointer is on heap:
   `int *val = new int(15);`
2. If the variable `val` is on stack and is passed by reference then the following syntax should be used in the initializer list to copy it to the heap and then let the pointer point to the location on heap:
   `ptr(new int(v1))`
3. Create an object of b1 on heap and then the code works fine. **This is still a mystery** because the in this case the `val` is still on stack and `ptr` points to address of the stack (`ptr(&v1)` in initializer list)
   `int val = 15;
   base *b1 = new base(val);
   cout << "b1.ptr  " << *(b1->ptr) << endl;`

Answer (score 0):

Both answers have pointed out the cause. I just want to add, you can do a [live test](https://segfault.stensal.com/a/0nqvJlH4y9GkaVux) to see it yourself.

The following is the more informative runtime error of your code.

=========== Start of #0 stensal runtime message ===========

Runtime error: **[freeing a stack memory space]**
  Continuing execution can cause undefined behavior, abort!

```
-
- the memory-space-to-be-freed (start:0xffd73a3c, size:4 bytes) is bound to 'val' at
-     file:/prog.cc::18, 9
- 
- Stack trace (most recent call first) of the error.
- [1]  file:/musl-1.1.10/src/malloc/new_dts_memory_util.c::20, 5
- [2]  file:/musl-1.1.10/src/malloc/safe_malloc.c::99, 3
- [3]  file:/src/new.cpp::124, 9
- [4]  @[unknown_id 291]
- [5]  file:/prog.cc::13, 9
- [6]  file:/prog.cc::21, 5
- [7]  [libc-start-main]
-
```

(104,331)

============ End of #0 stensal runtime message ============